# Type missmatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to String

Tags: java, string

I don't understand whats wrong with the following example:

```
public class String 
{
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "Hello";
    }
}
```

It says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to String"

on the String s line. I tried to Import java.lang.String but didn't help.

Comment: because the `String s = "Hello"` does refer to the class you're defining. If your package is "*com.mypackage*", `s` is not a `java.lang.String` but a `com.mypackage.String`

Comment: Don't name your class String.  Just don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you need to name your class as `String` ?

Change

```
public class String
```

To something else, like

```
public class SomethingElse
```

alternatively use qualified type name for you variable `s` (but still strongy recommend you not naming your classes like stuff from `java.lang` package)

```
java.lang.String s = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class name to something else, you cannot use string as your class name.

Java already has a class called String, it creates a conflict.

Comment: How does this different from the existing answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Strings1 {  // class name should not be String

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        // String basic program
        // class name should not be saved as String

        String s="Hello";
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```